# Jquery/Ajax and IE issue

Tags: jquery, svn

I am having trouble getting my Ajax call from the server. I am using SVN version control and my codes work in my side but have troubles after I push my codes to the production side.

The codes works in FF, Chrome and IE on my side.

For server, FF and chrome are working but only IE has problems.

I was wondering if anyone here can help me out. Thanks a lot.

I have

```
//call ajax function
callAjaxToCheck();


//call this function if there are errors
//I am getting Not connect.\n Verify Network error whose status == 0 when using IE on server side only!!!!!

function error_loading(jqXHR, exception){
    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
        alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
        alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
        alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
        alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
        alert('Time out error.');
    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
        alert('Ajax request aborted.');
    } else {
        alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
    }                 
}

function success(data) { 
    if (data=='jump') {
        $.getScript('inc/haha.js', function() {

            codes....

        });
    }
}


function callAjaxToCheck(){  
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Session.php',
        success: success,
        dataType: "text"
        error: error_loading
    });   
}
```

**Updated Codes:**

Please see my server side file.

I am sure my ajax function is called...

```
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
    session_start();

     if(isset($_POST['switch'])){
         $_SESSION['image']=$_POST['switch'];

     }

     echo $_SESSION['image'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `cache` to *false* in jQuery Ajax call.

```
function callAjaxToCheck() {  
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Session.php',
        cache: false,
        success: success,
        dataType: "text",
        error: error_loading
    });  
}
```

Comment: Oddly enough this worked for me when I was trying to debug why IE11 wasn't sending my cookies along with certain ajax calls

Answer (score 1):

`jqXHR.status === 0` means that nothing was returned from the server - which could likely mean a fatal error on the PHP side or something client-side cancelling the request.

Does your `Session.php` code rely on a session already existing at all - what happens if the session is failed to be found? I only ask because Internet Explorer has a different security model to the other browsers when it comes down to sending cookies across AJAX requests in certain sandboxes - more often than not it's policy is to not send any cookies at all (does your PHP take this into account?).

On the client side, what are you using to trigger your `callAjaxToCheck()`. I know in the code above it is directly called in the run of the program. However, that might just be a simplification in order to post on stackoverflow. Is that AJAX call ever triggered by a button or a link?

I realise there are a few questions here and no real stated answer, so I'll make an educated guess and state that it is most probably a session/cookie problem. With that in mind it may help to implement a [P3P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P) Policy, this can tell IE to send cookies across AJAX requests - you have to set the right policy to do so however... which can be a little tricky; which is why most developers looking for a quick fix just copy and paste the following into the top of the PHP file they are requesting:

```
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```

I don't recommend this however, but it can be a quick way to find out if it helps or not.

Comment: I have added your p3p codes and still not working...please see my updated codes..thx. +1

Comment: @FlyingCat - hmmm, in that case then all I can suggest is that you install 'fiddler' or something that will allow you to check over the AJAX call in Internet Explorer to get some more information on the request. As from my research I can't see anything that could cause the problem aside from strict security settings in IE or a firewall blocking the request. Also, did you try Jithesh Balakrishnan's answer of setting `cache` to false?